# Reloading rake task methods from byebug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, ruby-debug, byebug

I use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) debugger to pause execution of a rather lengthy rake task and inspect objects.

Is it possible to add a new completely method and somehow reload the rake task's code while I'm in byebug? For example, add a new method, reload byebug, verify it works, and move on without restarting the rake task..

Thanks!

Comment: Just defining required methods in the buebug console should work just fine.

Comment: Hi @Uzbekjon, thanks for your reply.
If I try to paste a multi-line method byebug executes each line separately so I get an error. For example, I try pasting:
`def try_method(whatever)
 puts whatever
end`
_and I get the error_ 
**SyntaxError Exception: (byebug):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input**

Comment: Hmmm... That's weird. Try to change your multi-line method definition into one liner: `def try_method(whatever); puts whatever; end`. But again, that's weird! :)

Comment: Thanks @Uzbekjon. Converting methods into one line is not practical, I might as well stop execution, type the method and re-run the rake task.
What about you? can you paste a multiline statement into byebug and run this successfully?